# electron-builder outputs error: Compressor "xz" is not supported

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to build an AppImage on my Raspberry Pi with electron-builder, but I am getting an error:

```
cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
errorOut=/home/pi/.cache/electron-builder/appimage/appimage-12.0.1/linux-arm32/mksquashfs: Compressor "xz" is not supported!
/home/pi/.cache/electron-builder/appimage/appimage-12.0.1/linux-arm32/mksquashfs: Compressors available:
gzip (default)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue and be able to build an AppImage file for my electron application?

The build options are:

```
"linux": {
"artifactName": "App Setup.${ext}",
"executableName": "App Name",
"category": "Utility",
"target": {
  "target": "appimage",
  "arch": [
    "armv7l"
  ]
}
```

}

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for info, I was able to build it by setting:
"compression": "normal",
in my electron settings.
The documentation says that there is not much size difference anyway.
Hope this helps anyone.